# Regex: mask characters from template in the string to end of line

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to retrieve part of string which starts from "Notes:" mask and until end of line (\n) character. There are could be any characters in between.

For example, something like:

**Notes: Advise ETA to shipper and deliver direct**

I'm trying to use following expression:

```
/[\w]*Notes[\s]*:[\s]*(?<notes>[.\S\s]*)$/is
```

However it doesn't stop at the end of line.

Could you please suggest me how can I do this

Comment: Please include the exact output you expect here.

Comment: Try: `/[\w]*Notes[\s]*:[\s]*(?<notes>.*$/mi - not the `m` flag.

Answer (score 0):

After few more time of investigation I was able to do it with following regex:

```
/[\w]*Notes[\s]*:[\s]*(?<notes>[a-zA-Z0-9 \t!"\#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_‘{|}~]*)/mi
```